# simple progress bar using JQuery does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, progress-bar

I'm a newbie in JavaScript, I'm responsible for an online quiz (html5 code), which takes long time to execute "startgame" function (construct the html for 100 questions).So I add a progress bar,

```
   function startgame()
   {    
    var progress=0;
    for (index = 0; index < numberofquestions; index++) {
    progress=index+"%";
    $("#progress-bar").css("width",progress);
    ...
    }
    ...}
```

and progress-bar is the id of a div in the html code

```
<div id="progress-bar" style="width:0%; background:blue;opacity:1;height:25px;"/>`
```

which works as expected (the width of the bar is increasing) when I step over the for loop, however, it does not work at all if I remove the break point and run (the progress will stay at 0% or the point I stop debugging)
I‘ve also tried

```
document.getElementById("progress-bar").outerHTML='<div id="progress-bar"          style="width:'+progress+';background:blue;opacity:1; display:block; height:25px;"'+'/>';
```

to replace
    $("#progress-bar").css("width",progress);
 but the result is same as before

Comment: `" which takes long time to execute "startgame" function (construct the html for 100 questions"` your priority should be to optimize the appending of those 100 questios because it's not that much data & it should not take such a long time that you'd need a progress bar

Answer (score 1):

numberofquestions.length should give you the entire length of the array numberofquestions.  You're missing all the code so besides that can't say..

Comment: my difficult is to get the progress bar moving, with the iterations of for loop, thanks anyway